# conditional where on laravel query builder returns no result

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, query-builder

I'm trying to do a conditional where query based on the supplied parameter, however, it returns no result whereas when I put the entire query directly to query builder it does return a result because there is that specific data in the table. Here's what I currently have

```
$tasks = DB::table('customer_master')->select(DB::raw("customer_name,
    substring(birthday,1,4)||' - '||substring(birthday,5,2)||' - '||substring(birthday,7,2) as dob"));
    
if (isset($idCustomer)){
    $tasks->where('customer_id', $idCustomer);
}

$tasks->first();
return $tasks;
```

The return is as follows:

```
{"data":{"connection":{},"grammar":{},"processor":{},"bindings":{"select":[],"from":[],"join":[],"where":["0001108032"],"groupBy":[],"having":[],"order":[],"union":[],"unionOrder":[]},"aggregate":null,"columns":[{}],"distinct":false,"from":"customer_master","joins":null,"wheres":[{"type":"Basic","column":"customer_id","operator":"=","value":"0001108032","boolean":"and"}],"groups":null,"havings":null,"orders":null,"limit":1,"offset":null,"unions":null,"unionLimit":null,"unionOffset":null,"unionOrders":null,"lock":null,"operators":["=","<",">","<=",">=","<>","!=","<=>","like","like binary","not like","ilike","&","|","^","<<",">>","rlike","not rlike","regexp","not regexp","~","~*","!~","!~*","similar to","not similar to","not ilike","~~*","!~~*"],"useWritePdo":false}}
```

Please help to point out where am I getting this wrong. Thanks

Comment: you should use return $tasks->first() instead of Database Object $tasks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this instead:

```php
$tasks =  DB::table('customer_master')
        ->select(DB::raw("customer_name,
        substring(birthday,1,4)||' - '||substring(birthday,5,2)||' - '||substring(birthday,7,2) as dob"));
        
if (isset($idCustomer)){
    $tasks->where('customer_id', $idCustomer);
}

return $tasks->first();
```